Name of the Hollywood movie where main characters are teenages and the child actress looks like Kaitlyn Dever?

This Hollywood movie was released between 2000 and 2015. 
It's teenage Romantic movie.
The girl looks exactly like Kaitlyn Dever character in movie Bad Teacher.

4.The movie is from girl's narration point of view.
5.The main characters are a teenage boy and girl both in Same class in middle or high school and are also neighbours living on opposite side of the streets.

The movie is set in 90's or earlier.

7.The girl is weird and shy and her classmates tease her a lot.
8.The girl likes the boy and the boy also likes the girl but he is confused and tries to stay away from girl because rumours are that she is weird.
9.The girl bonds with boy's grandfather over Gardening.

The boy's family think the girl's family is weird.
The girl has an elder brother who is in a Mental Asylum. And she goes to visit him with her father during the movie.

Can someone help me with the movie name?

It sounds very similar to "Flipped"
In Flipped:

The boy and girl live across the street from each other
The girl has a mentally challenged uncle, whom she visits with her father
The girl is weird and teased
The girl loves to garden


"Juli Baker devoutly believes in three things: the sanctity of trees (especially her beloved sycamore), the wholesomeness of the eggs she collects from her backyard flock of chickens, and that someday she will kiss Bryce Loski. Ever since she saw Bryce's dazzling brown eyes back in second grade, Juli has been smitten. Unfortunately, Bryce has never felt the same. Frankly, he thinks Juli Baker is a little weird--after all, what kind of freak raises chickens and sits in trees for fun? Then, in eighth grade, everything changes. Bryce begins to see that Juli's unusual interests and pride in her family are, well, kind of cool. And Juli starts to think that maybe Bryce's dazzling brown eyes are as empty as the rest of Bryce seems to be. After all, what kind of jerk doesn't care about other people's feelings about chickens and trees? With Flipped, mystery author Wendelin Van Draanen has taken a break from her Sammy Keyes series, and the result is flipping fantastic. Bryce and Juli's rants and raves about each other ring so true that teen readers will quickly identify with at least one of these hilarious feuding egos, if not both. A perfect introduction to the adolescent war between the sexes."





Thanks. This is the exact movie I was talking about.
